# Send \r\n in vb6 for http response

Tags: html, websocket, vb6

I am attempting to write a websocket server in VB6 and have now figured out i am not sending `\r\n` in the response, how do i do that in VB6? `vbNewLine` and `vbCr & vbLf` does not work.

```
Private Sub Winsock1_DataArrival(ByVal bytesTotal As Long)
Dim sData As String
    Dim guid
    guid = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"


    Winsock1.GetData sData
    request.Text = sData
    Dim aintCount()
     Dim pos As Integer
    Dim entry() As String
    Dim entry2() As String

    entry = Split(sData, vbCrLf, , vbTextCompare)

    pos = 0




    Do While pos < UBound(entry)
        If Trim$(entry(pos)) <> "" Then
        'Text3.Text = entry(pos)
            entry2 = Split(entry(pos), ":", , vbTextCompare)
            If entry2(0) = "Sec-WebSocket-Key" Then
            Text3.Text = Trim(entry2(1) & guid)

            End If
        End If
        pos = pos + 1
    Loop




    Dim Packet() As Byte

    'Dim response As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols" & Environment.NewLine & "Connection: Upgrade" & Environment.NewLine & "Upgrade: websocket" & Environment.NewLine & "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " & Convert.ToBase64String(System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(New Regex("Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)").Match(data).Groups(1).Value.Trim() & "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"))) & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine)

    crypt.EncodingMode = "base64"
    crypt.HashAlgorithm = "sha1"



    'Text1.Text = crypt.HashBytesENC(Bytes)
        Bytes = StrConv(Trim(entry2(1) & "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"), vbFromUnicode)
        Text1.Text = crypt.HashBytesENC(Bytes)
         '"HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols" & Environment.NewLine & "Connection: Upgrade" & Environment.NewLine & "Upgrade: websocket" & Environment.NewLine & "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: "
    Packet = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols" & Crlf & "Connection: Upgrade" & Crlf & "Upgrade: WebSocket" & Crlf & "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " & crypt.HashBytesENC(StrConv(Trim(entry2(1) & "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"), vbFromUnicode)) & vbCr & vbLf

        'Packet = Packet & "Upgrade: WebSocket" & vbCr & vbNewLine
        'Packet = Packet & "Connection: Upgrade" & vbCr & vbNewLine
        'Packet = Packet & "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " & crypt.HashBytesENC(Bytes) & vbCr & vbNewLine

        'Data = Empty
       response.Text = Packet
    Winsock1.SendData Packet
End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating what you are attempting and what does not work for you.

Comment: Did you try `vbCrLf`?

Comment: You've defined packet as an array of byte, but you are setting it as though it is a string. Setting Packet = something & vbCr & vbLf will result in packet containing 3 bytes for the vbCr, vbLf 13, 0, and 10. Try using the StrConv( FromUnicode) function on the entire string. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to use the minimum code from the OP to provide an example. I don't know what the `crypt` function returns. It is very possible you'll want to include that inside the StrConv function as well. If so that will make it easier as you will not have to encrypt and concatenate the string in pieces. You will probably be able to look as response.Text to determine if you need to do the StrConv on the individual pieces or if you can do it on the whole string.

```
...

    Dim Packet() As Byte

    crypt.EncodingMode = "base64"
    crypt.HashAlgorithm = "sha1"

    Bytes = StrConv(Trim(entry2(1) & "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"), vbFromUnicode)
    Text1.Text = crypt.HashBytesENC(Bytes)

    'Either
    Packet = StrConv("HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols" & vbCrLf & "Connection: Upgrade" & vbCrLf & "Upgrade: WebSocket" & vbCrLf & "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: ", vbFromUnicode) & crypt.HashBytesENC(StrConv(Trim(entry2(1) & "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"), vbFromUnicode)) & StrConv(vbCrLf, vbFromUnicode)

    'Or
    Packet = StrConv("HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols" & vbCrLf & "Connection: Upgrade" & vbCrLf & "Upgrade: WebSocket" & vbCrLf & "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " & crypt.HashBytesENC(StrConv(Trim(entry2(1) & "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"), vbFromUnicode)) & vbCrLf, vbFromUnicode)

    response.Text = StrConv(Packet, vbUnicode)
    Winsock1.SendData Packet

...
```

Comment: Not working still:( adding the strconv did allow fiddler to see a http response but I am unable to connect